# Slickgrid Custom MultiSelectEditor Working Only with FireFox 17.0.1

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I've extend SlickGrid's Editor, tu support html Select and MultiSelect. Here is the MultiSelectEditor source:

```
function PickListEditor(args) {

      var $select;
      var defaultValue ;
      var scope = this;

      this.init = function() {
          console.log("PickListEditor...  SelectValues");
          console.log(args.column.columnSelectItems);
          option_str = ""
          var length =  args.column.columnSelectItems.length;
          for(var i = 0; i< length ; i++){
              var selectOption = args.column.columnSelectItems[i];
              if(selectOption["disable"]==true) disable = "disable";
              option_str += "<OPTION value='"+selectOption["stringValue"]+"'>"+selectOption["label"]+"</OPTION>";
          }
          $select = $("<select tabIndex='0' multiple='multiple'>"+ option_str +"</select>");
          console.log(args.container);
          $select.appendTo(args.container);
          $(args.container).append($select[0]); 
          console.log($select);
          console.log($select[0]);
          $select.focus();
      };

      this.destroy = function() {
          $select.remove();
      };

      this.focus = function() {
          $select.focus();
      };

      this.loadValue = function(item) {
          console.log("loaded Item  : ");
          console.log(item);
          defaultValue = item[args.column.field];
          $select.val(defaultValue);
      };

      this.serializeValue = function() {
          if(args.column.columnSelectItems){
            return $select.val();
          }else{
            return "";
          }
      };

      this.applyValue = function(item,state) {
          item[args.column.field] = state;
      };

      this.isValueChanged = function() {
          return ($select.val() != defaultValue);
      };

      this.validate = function() {
          return {
              valid: true,
              msg: null
          };
      };

      this.init();
}
```

The multi select work fine on firefox 17.0 . But on chrome 23.0.1271.95 or safari  6.0.2 , I the multiselect is displayed, but I can't select Items.

Do someone have any Idea ?

Cheers,
Boris.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:
[image: Example image]

```
function SelectsEditor(args) {
    var $select;
    var defaultValue;
    var scope = this;

    this.init = function () {
        var option_str = "";
        for (key in args.column.options) {
            option_str += "<OPTION value='" + key + "'>" + args.column.options[key] + "</OPTION>";
        }
        $select = $("<SELECT tabIndex='0' class='editor-select' multiple='multiple'>" + option_str + "</SELECT>");
        $select.appendTo(args.container);
        $select.focus();
    };

    this.destroy = function () {
        $select.remove();
    };

    this.focus = function () {
        $select.focus();
    };

    this.loadValue = function (item) {
        defaultValue = item[args.column.field];
        $select.val(defaultValue);
    };

    this.serializeValue = function () {
        return $select.val();
    };

    this.applyValue = function (item, state) {
        item[args.column.field] = state;
    };

    this.isValueChanged = function () {
        return ($select.val() != defaultValue);
    };

    this.validate = function () {
        return {
            valid: true,
            msg: null
        };
    };

    this.init();
}
```